# How I get & validate the username and password in SQL Management using API?

Tags: sql, ionic3, angular2-forms

I created my login page and i want to validate the username and password. Then i need to get the user details using API from the database. please send me a coding using ionic-3 and angular-2.

I already tried in my SQL. But  i want it in SQL management. In the below coding i send the parameters using `post` method and it will get at back end and validate with already registered username and password.

```
Username: any;
Password: any;
```

### data:string;

```
constructor(  ){}
 //declaration of object//

   var headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

  let option = new RequestOptions({headers: headers });

let data = {

  username: this.Username.value,

  password: this.Password.value

  };

  let loader = this.loading.create({

   spinner: 'bubbles',
   duration: 1000
  });

  //API call//
  loader.present().then(() => {

  this.http.post('')

  .map(res => res.json())

  .subscribe(res => {

  console.log(res)

  loader.dismiss()

  if(res=="Your Login Success"){

  let alert = this.altCtrl.create({

  title:"CONGRATS",

  subTitle:(res),

  buttons: ['OK']

  });

  alert.present().then(()=>
  this.navCtrl.push(NextPage));

  }
  else{

  let alert = this.altCtrl.create({

  title:"ERROR",

  subTitle:"Your Login Username or Password is invalid",

  buttons: ['OK']

  });

  alert.present();

  }

  },(err) => {

  });

  });

  }
```

I expect if the username or password is wrong it should show alert "username or password incorrect". in else it will push to the next page with "your login success".

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

in your Login.ts

```
let loginObject = {
   username: userInputValueFromUsername
   password: userInputValueFromPassword
} 

this.headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}; // set Headers for the Request
this.http.post('https://somew-url.com/api/login', JSON.stringify(loginObject), {headers: this.headers})
       .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
          if (data.success == true) {
              //push to new Page
          }
          else{
          // Show Error
          }
      });
```