# HTTP Post request not sending body or param data from ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

HTTP post request is not sending body or param data to the server

Forgive me if this turns out to be a duplicate question. I've looked at several similar questions on stack overflow, but none of them have solved my problem. Also tried using a GET request instead of a POST request, but body data is still not sending.

Client side code:

```
// ionic code
homeUrl: string = 'http://localhost:80';
let obj = {"name": "Guest"};
let response = this.httpClient.post(this.homeUrl + '/admin-signup', JSON.stringify(obj));
    response.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('response: ', data);
      //TODO: handle HTTP errors
    });
```

Server side code:

```
server.post('/admin-signup', (req, res) => {
  console.log('sign')
  console.log(req.body);
  // TODO: Process request
  res
    .status(200)
    .send(JSON.parse('{"message": "Hello, signup!"}'))
    .end();
});
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57179588/5909026

Comment: also share your log data, if you have any error

Comment: Thanks. Not getting any errors on either the server or client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, import http client

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Then do the following

```
const header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       Accept: 'application/json'
       //api token (if need)
});    
const options = {
       headers: header
}
let response = this.httpClient.post(this.homeUrl + '/admin-signup', obj, options);
        response.toPromise().then(data => {
          console.log('response: ', data);
          //TODO: handle HTTP errors
        }).catch((err) =>{
           console.log('error', err);
        });
```

Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: Seems like progress... I'm now getting a CORS error... **has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Comment: you need to add CORS in your server side. Follow this article.
https://alazierplace.com/2019/06/cors-cross-origin-communication-in-the-modern-web/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ionic 
but I'm guessing its a cors issue

can you try use cors?

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into cors. Would I use it on the server side? The server is receiving the request but the body object is empty. Does that seem like a cors issue?

Comment: Uh, so maybe the problem is with the content-type?

could you try send the request this way?

const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };

this.httpClient.post(this.homeUrl + '/admin-signup', JSON.stringify(obj), headers);

Comment: Yes you can send request like this.

Comment: @TheoScottVanZyl is the request with headers worked?

Comment: Thanks, I will try the headers approach... Got sidetracked with another task.

Comment: @Elad It seems not. When I add the headers I get the error: error TS2559: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.